# scikit-learn: StandardScaler() freezes in comb. with Pipeline and GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, scaling, grid-search

I am trying to fit a model onto a dataset with the following construction:

```
# Import stuff and generate dataset.
import sklearn as skl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn import metrics
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from shutil import rmtree
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Memory
X, y = skl.datasets.make_classification(n_samples=1400, n_features=11,  n_informative=5, n_classes=2, weights=[0.94, 0.06], flip_y=0.05, random_state=42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = skl.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)


# 1. Instantiate a scaler. 
#normer = preprocessing.Normalizer()
normer = preprocessing.StandardScaler()

# 2. Instantiate a Linear Support Vector Classifier.
svm1 = svm.SVC(probability=True, class_weight={1: 10})

# 3. Forge normalizer and classifier into a pipeline. Make sure the pipeline steps are memorizable during the grid search.
cached = mkdtemp()
memory = Memory(cachedir=cached, verbose=1)
pipe_1 = Pipeline(steps=[('normalization', normer), ('svm', svm1)], memory=memory)

# 4. Instantiate Cross Validation
cv = skl.model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# 5. Instantiate the Grid Search for Hypereparameter Tuning
params = [ {"svm__kernel": ["linear"], "svm__C": [1, 10, 100, 1000]}, 
           {"svm__kernel": ["rbf"], "svm__C": [1, 10, 100, 1000], "svm__gamma": [0.001, 0.0001]} ]
grd = GridSearchCV(pipe_1, params, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv)
```

The program freezes in my Jupyter notebook when calling

```
y_pred = grd3.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
```

I aborted after 20 minutes.
When I use preprocessing.Normalizer() instead of StandardScaler, the .fit() is done after two or three minutes.

What could be the problem here?

Edit: here is the output from the GridSearchCV():

```
GridSearchCV(cv=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=2, shuffle=True), error_score='raise',estimator=Pipeline(memory=None, steps=[('normalization', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True)), ('svm', SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight={1: 10}, coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=True, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False))]), fit_params=None, iid=True, n_jobs=1,param_grid=[{'svm__kernel': ['linear'], 'svm__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}, {'svm__kernel': ['rbf'], 'svm__C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'svm__gamma': [0.001, 0.0001]}],pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score=True, scoring='roc_auc', verbose=0)
```

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd. Can you give us some data so we can reproduce the error? Also, might want to add verbose = 2 (or 5) so you can see the folds that your GridSearchCV was testing. It might've been running but not telling ya

Comment: If I set verbose, the printouts stop after the fifth block or so

Comment: revise your post with the GridSearchCV output after running for 45mins. The RBF kernel of SVN generally takes a lot of time to fit anyway so that's probably your "freezing"

Comment: do you mean grd.best_param_?

Comment: Nah, the text sent to the console from `GridSearchCV(pipe_1, params, verbose = 2, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv)`

Comment: edited OP to insert the console text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160465/discussion-between-plumbus-bouquet-and-ulu83).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answering my comments (and I didn't see your data gen code, my bad).

You had a typo in your code, it should be:

`y_pred = grd.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]`

Not:

`y_pred = grd3.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]`

But from the logs it doesn't appear to be freezing but gets VERRRRY slow when testing C = 1000 in your grid search.

Does it need to be this high???

**Testing on my computer (for the linear kernel, RBF will likely take even longer):**

SVM_C = [10, 100, 1000] takes [1.8s, 16s, 127s]

So I'd recommend just testing up to C = 200/500 unless you're planning to run this overnight in a multi-fold CV grid search.

**More generally**

The both the fit function of a grid search and the predict probability functions can take a large amount of time.

I'd recommend splitting them in to two steps so you can mitigate the chance of freezing.

`grd.fit(X_train, y_train)`

`y_pred = grd.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]`

Comment: verbose=2 led to the solution!